# time.localtime() - how does it work? Brief questions on how to use it too - super easy stuff!

Tags: python, arrays, time

How does time.localtime() work exactly?  I can call up the "array" (tupple, I think it is called - because it is immutable?) and reference/index components of it.  For example:

```
>>> time.localtime()[0]
2010
```

But if I do:

```
print time.localtime()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=14, tm_min=46, tm_sec=58, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=38, tm_isdst=0)
```

First:  How does time.localtime() know to return time.struct_time()?

Second:  If I type print time.struct_time() it wants additional values to be passed to it  (thus not giving me the same values it returned from time.localtime()) - how do I know what those values could possibly be?  I checked the python documentation and I couldn't make 'heads nor tails' of it. Really just looking for an example here...

Third:  When I index the tupple/array for time.localtime() it returns the proper associated value, "2010" for example, rather than "tm_year=2010" - how does it know to do this (generally speaking not asking for a lot here).

Forth:  If I wanted to "call" tm_year from time.localtime() how can I do this?  What I am doing (and don't 'feel' right about) is the following:

```
tm_year = str(time.localtime()[0])
tm_mon = str(time.localtime()[1])
tm_mday = str(time.localtime()[2])
tm_hour = str(time.localtime()[3])
tm_min = str(time.localtime()[4])
```

NOTE: I am saving them as strings for other reasons not explained in this question, just wanted to point out that I am creating my own variables (named exactly the same as they are in the tupple) and then just referencing the index value associated with the value I want

Is there a way to to just call time.localtime(tm_year) (I know that doesn't work as is, but just brainstorming...)

Thanks in advance... (and I have read "http://docs.python.org/library/time.html" but I am sure I missed some important information... any advice?)

-J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time.localtime()[0]` calls `__gettiem__()` on the `time.struct_time` instance. This is how it gets this list/tuple like behaviour from. Here is a really simple example

```
>>> class MyTime(object):
...     def __init__(self, year, month, mday, hour, minute):
...         self.data =  year, month, mday, hour, minute
...     def __getitem__(self, idx):
...         return self.data[idx]
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "MyTime(tm_year=%s, tm_mon=%s, tm_mday=%s, tm_hour=%s, tm_min=%s)"%self.data
... 
>>> x=MyTime(2010,2,7,14,46)
>>> x[0]
2010
>>> x[1]
2
>>> print x
MyTime(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=14, tm_min=46)
```

`time.struct_time` is a class. `time.localtime()` returns an instance of the class, which explains the difference when you try to print them

You can load up your 5 variables like this

```
>>> tm_year,tm_mon,tm_mday,tm_hour,tm_min=map(str,time.localtime()[:5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own "named tuples", i.e., subclasses of `tuple` with items accessible by either indexing or as attributes, with [collections.namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) (in Python 2.6 or better). There's nothing "magical" about named tuples in general, nor specifically about the one whose instances are returned by various functions in the `time` module (which is slightly different, because it predates `collections.namedtuple`).

So, for example, `time.localtime().tm_year` will give you the year, as you want (you can pass it to `str` and/or assign it to anything you want, of course).

But since you can also access the result as a tuple, you have alternatives such as slicing, tuple-unpacking, and the like.

When you call `time.struct_time`, you're building an arbitrary instance of it -- and you need to pass it one argument, a sequence with exactly nine items.  (For a normal named tuple that's similar to it, you'd pass nine arguments instead -- of course it's easy to pass nine arguments if you have a nine-sequence `foo`, i.e., you call `bar(*foo)`;-).

By the way, you focus on `localtime`, but that's not the only function returning a `struct_time`, of course -- `gmtime` and `strptime` return instances of the same type!-)

Answer (score 0):

1. The `print` statement tries to convert all its arguments to a string representation. And the `__repr__`  or `__str__` method of a struct_time object yields the result

   time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=14, tm_min=46, tm_sec=58, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=38, tm_isdst=0)

   See the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement)
2. Don't use it. It's an internal data structure
3. When you use the index-operator `[]` it behaves like a tuple

Comment: dont use repr or str because they are internal data structures? Or don't try to call time.struct_time? Is that because I can potentially alter some sort of sensitive system value? Or is it just 'bad form'/bad practice? (edited to fix wording)

Answer (score 0):

Nascent Notes,

The function `time.localtime()` accepts an optional argument of [Epoch seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch), without the argument it takes the current time (probably from `time.time()`). The function then calculates what time this corresponds to in your timezone (i.e. your local time) and then returns the results in object of type time.struct_time.

I'm not sure why you want to create a `struct_time` object, as you're asking about the what the arguments should be, perhaps you're heading in the wrong direction.

It seems that you're interested in manipulating representations of time. I think that the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) may be more suitable for your purposes.